# RouteURL and null issue?

Tags: c#

All,

Still learning this stuff so not sure what I am missing.

Here is the path I want to pass to the server.

```
model.CreditReportHistoryRoute = Url.RouteUrl(CreditReportHistoryDialogController.RouteGetInitialData, new { databaseId = 12345 }).Replace("12345", "{databaseId}");
```

databaseId is null when I run the code (at the end of the above line).

A few lines above this code runs fine

```
model.ReportRoute = Url.RouteUrl(RequestReportRoute, new { subjectId = 12345 }).Replace("12345", "{subjectId}");
```

Here is the controller/route code

```
public sealed class CreditReportHistoryDialogController : WebAccessApiController
{
    public const string RouteGetInitialData = "CreditReportHistoryDialog.GetDataForDatabase";

    [Route("{databaseId:int}", Name = RouteGetInitialData), MemberAccess, HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetInitialData(int databaseId)
    {
        return Ok(databaseId);
    }
```

Thx
jonpfl

Comment: Your `Replace()` call at the end gets executed immediately. Depending on where your code is running, your `databaseId` property used to create the URL is most likely blank.

Comment: There is similar code a few lines above that works fine using the same syntax.  model.ReportRoute = Url.RouteUrl(RequestReportRoute, new { subjectId = 12345 }).Replace("12345", "{subjectId}");